# React resetting or clearing inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reset or clear my inputs once the form submits.

Can someone please tell me how to do this. I have tried to recall this.state.user so that it starts back with the empty strings but that has not helped. In this scenario what must I do in order to get the inputs to clear once the form has submitted.

I tried recalling the page using `history.push('/register');` and `dispatch(reset('form'));` but unfortunately still does not clear the inputs

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
            dispatch(userActions.register(user));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { registering  } = this.props;
        const { user, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                            <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username = user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.username &&
                            <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.password &&
                            <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        {registering &&
                            <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                        }
                      {/*  <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link> */}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { registering } = state.registration;
    return {
        registering
    };
}

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterPage);
export { connectedRegisterPage as RegisterPage };
```

user actions

```
function register(user) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request(user));

        userService.register(user)
            .then(
                user => {
                    dispatch(success());
                  {/*  history.push('/register'); */}
                    dispatch(alertActions.success('Registration successful'));
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me, although it triggers all error messages when the fields clear

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { user } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
        dispatch(userActions.register(user));
    }

    this.setState({
      submitted: true,
      user: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Because `submitted` become `true`

Comment: `true && !"" && <Component />` will always render ("" being empty string).

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it fixed your problem? :) And yes. You could run a validation function on submit and setting flags for each input if they are empty strings (instead of submitting), although there are many different approaches you could use. Consider asking another question if you can't figure it out :)

Comment: Sure. Post another question and I'll take a look